# Can't authenticate using JWT in MVC client

Tags: c#, jwt, identityserver4, identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I've set up the following authentication in my MVC client.

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
services.AddAuthentication(_ =>
{
  //_.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
  //_.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
  _.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
  .AddCookie("Cokies")
  .AddFacebook()
  .AddGoogle()
  .AddJwtBearer()
  .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", _ => { });
```

Since the default is set to JWT, I imagine that the others (*Cookie*, *Facebook*, *Google* and *OpenIdConnect*) are simply disregarded if the authorization decorator is invoked with no parameters.

However, I simply get *401 Unauthorized* with no additional information. For instance, if I comment out the default scheme statement for JWT and activate the cookie one like this:

```
{
  _.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
  _.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
  //_.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}...
```

I get developer error page saying that client ID is unknown. But in this case, I only get the default page in Chrome with the error code. I was considering that maybe the default challenge scheme needs to be set but it makes no sense to do that for JWT, right? Also, I see no field for that in *JwtBearerDefaults* class.

What am I missing in my MVC client to make it authenticate properly? Or is the issue in my configuration of the IDS4?

I've googled for a while but I'm not getting any hits that talk to me and that I'd recognize as meaningful. Might be my ignorance, though...

A shorter version still producing the same issue looks like this.

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(_ =>
  {
    _.Authority = "https://localhost:44300";
    _.Audience = "http://localhost:5001";
  });
```

My IDS4 runs on port 44300 (checked with *.well-known*) and the API is on port 5001.

Comment: Can you share JWT token that is produced during authentication? Also any reason why you don’t use idsrv4 nuget package for the token validation?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Thanks for the reply, mate. Regarding the token - how can I obtain it in "clear view". I navigate to an endpoint decorated by *[Authorize]* and then the black magic of IDS happens. What do I miss? Regarding the validation, I have *IDS4.AccessTokenValidation* package installed but I might be confused as to its usage. It's supposed to be installed in the *IdServer* project, not the *MvcClientApp* project, right? (I've scrutinized the IDS guide and it's good but starts to become a bit obsolete and gets a bit jumpy between the topics. So - it's my incompetence and confusion.

Comment: If this is the actual code then `.AddCookie("Cokies")` may be one issue. As for the NuGet package, the API is the project where the package is required: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/Api/Api.csproj

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I thought so too so I removed all of that (last part of the question mentions it). Still the same issue remains. I'm pretty confident it's me doing something dumb and not seeing what. Or rather - I miss adding something needed rather than I've added something faulty. As for the link - I've been through them but, as I pointed out, most of the samples are a bit obsolete (e.g. we're supposed to use extension methods to *HttpClient* now instead of specialized classes for obtaining URLs and such). I want to target Core 2.2/IDS4 and I'm yet to find a good example/blog on that.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I got confused by the lack of *[/connect/accesstokenvalidation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/accessTokenValidation.html)* and saw [a post](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2288) that it's not usable anymore.

Comment: You can capture the token by inspecting network traffic in chrome dev tools for example. As for the package, it needs to be installed on the client side.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Oh, good - then I had it installed correctly at first. I have added the package to the MVC client again and removed it from ID server project. Now, examining the network tells me that I get a bunch of images (PNG and SVG) but nothing token-like at all... What stupid thing might I have missed? I feel terribly lost as to trouble-shooting this...

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I just realized something. In the definition of the client (which is done in the IDS4 project) I have set the redirect URL point to a page on the MVC application. Is that a problem? It shouldn't be, right? Or is it required that the login page is served from the project of Identity Server?

Comment: Redirect uri usually looks like `http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc` by default for ASP.NET Core MVC. You should be able to inspect traffic when you hit any page which has `[Authorize]` attribute on its controller. The traffic should start with a call to your identity server, then to external provider (if you use one), then back to identity server and lastly, callback to your MVC client. The callback is where the token usually would be in the response body.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I fear that my issue's deeper than I can explain. Perhaps it's because I'm using HTTPS or something. I'm hitting the endpoint with *[Authorize]* but in the Network tab I can't see anything about any jumps... As for the *RedirectURL*, it's supposed to point to a login page, right? So I'll have to activate static files on ID server project and produce a login page that looks stylistically like my MVC application, then. Is that correct?

Comment: RedirectUrl is usually the sign in page, not the login page. If you are using `.UseAuthentication()` ASP.NET Core middleware, it should be `http://yourdomain/signin-oidc`. Also can you then try without https?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I've removed the HTTPS and make only unsecure connections now. Same issue remains. As for the link you suggested - which of the applicaitons is it supposed ot point? I'm running both ID provider, API and MVC client on *localhost* just different ports (in production it will be different servers, of course). Which of the servers is *signin-oidc* supposed to be located on?

Comment: Sign in page is an in built end point to handle callback from oidc provider in the MVC client that you can create just by starting new asp.net core mvc project. You set that as the callback uri in the client setup within identity server. Where each component is hosted - same or different servers - doesn’t have any difference here since this protocol is http based.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Sorry for the delay. I was hospitalized. Now, I'm back. I'm a bit confused by the exact details of what *RedirectUrl* is supposed to point to. Are you saying (a) configure client definition in the setup of IDS4 and set *RedirectUri={"http://localhost:5002/home/login"}*? Or are you referring to (b) configuration of the MVC client's setup setting *services.AddAuthentication(...)...* somehow? Or perhaps (c) something else?

Comment: Referring to both actually. In idsrv4 client setup redirect url to be http://yoursiteurl/signin-oidc . If you want a working example just check idsrv4 quickstarts. It’s basically a handler endpoint in built in aspnetcore authentication middleware to sign your user in upon callback from identity provider.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Perhaps that's what was confusing me. Do I have to actually implement the endpoint (or static file) being reached at *localhost:5002/signin-oidc* (port 5002 is my MVC client application)? Or is it automagically handled by my call to *services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)*? I find the docs on the official site a bit vague on that.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Hey, check this answer I posted, it basically details what you need to set up on your MVC client and IDS4) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173177/getting-401-accessing-secured-page-with-jwttoken-under-ids4-and-asp-net-core-2-2/54181358#54181358 To answer your question - yes, the handler endpoints are in built with the authentication service middleware.